# Use tcpreplay .pcap with raw packet data fail

Tags: pcap, raw-ethernet, tcpreplay

I'm using tcpreplay to generate traffic from the `.pcap` file for my experiments. More specifically I'm using files from the `ISCX-VPN-NONVPN-2016` public dataset.

However, I'm having problems retransmitting encrypted traffic, as they present the L2 `Raw packet data` fields as shown in the image.

[image: pcap file without L2 headers]

The following error is displayed when I try to relay traffic:

```
~ # tcpreplay -i enp0s25 input.pcap
tcpreplay: flows.c:204: flow_decode: Assertion `l2len > 0' failed.
Aborted (core image recorded)
```

Is there any way to add ethernet headers in this case to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using the Tcpreplay [4.4.2-beta](https://github.com/appneta/tcpreplay/releases/tag/v4.4.2-beta1). This version
has only bug fixes. One of them is `heap-buffer-overflow in get_l2len_protocol()`.

Now it works perfectly.

```
tcpreplay -i enp0s25 input.pcap 
Actual: 422098 packets (369433883 bytes) sent in 224.07 seconds
Rated: 1648722.3 Bps, 13.18 Mbps, 1883.75 pps
Flows: 922 flows, 4.11 fps, 422098 flow packets, 0 non-flow
Statistics for network device: enp0s25
    Successful packets:        422098
    Failed packets:            0
    Truncated packets:         0
    Retried packets (ENOBUFS): 0
    Retried packets (EAGAIN):  0
```